# Refreshing code

Tags: android

Hi I want code for  refershing my page automatically when i click on any button.For Ex I have a people page In that page i delete people  from total peoples using one button but that selected people is not deleted immediately That means the People page is not refreshing.So,I want code for refreshing that page.Give me any suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter to refresh the ListView.